# ngrx how to get the stored value from selector instead of observable

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

I have the following code where I am trying to store a value to store and get it I have created a sample code for the same

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rfqf6h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I have created the following store

`action.ts`:

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
export const setTrackLength = createAction(
'[Track] Set Value',
props<{ lengthOfTrack: number }>()
);
```

`selector.ts`:

```
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { TrackState } from './track.state';

export const setTrackLength = createFeatureSelector<TrackState>('trackState');

export const getTrackLength = createSelector(
  setTrackLength,
  (state) => state.trackLength
);
```

I am storing and getting the value but it display as follows where I need the value to be 1

[image]

[image]

In the console I can see the value as per the second image I need that value to be read instead of entire observable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that output because you are not subscribing to the selector result.
Whenever you grab something from the `store` by using `selectors`, you will always get the value wrapped in an `observable`

Given your example, you need to subscribe to `getTrackLength` selector function like the following:

```js
// imperative way
myValue!: number | undefined;
subscription = new Subscription();

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.store.add(
    this.store.select(getTrackLength).subscribe((theValue) => this.myValue = theValue);
  )  
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.subscription?.unsubscribe();
}

onOptionsSelected() {
  this.store.dispatch(setTrackLength({ lengthOfTrack: 1 }));  
}
```

```js
// reactive way (the recommended way)
myValue$!: Observable<number | undefined>;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.myValue$ = this.store.select(getTrackLength);
}

onOptionsSelected() {
  this.store.dispatch(setTrackLength({ lengthOfTrack: 1 }));  
}
```

```html
<p *ngIf="myValue$ | async as result">The value selected is: {{ result }}</p>
```

In the second approach, you don't handle the `subscription`, you do that implicitly by using the `async` pipe giving you a better, simple approach for handling `observables`

More about `selectors` [here](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors)